# Specify drill down report based on condition

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am specifying following IIF condition in Textbox action property to run a drill through report:

```
=IIF(Fields!DeptName.Value="Department Total", Nothing, "TimekeeperTitlesMainBECReport")
```

When DeptName is not "Department Total" the texbox is properly clickable. However, it is clickable even when DeptName is "Department Total". I understand that both sides of IIF are executed. However, I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "clickable"-- if there is a value in Action, then you will always be able to click the object, however, it shouldn't cause the subreport to run or anything like that. One option would be to put the action on a separate object, and toggle visibility of that object via Fields!DeptName.Value

Comment: Do you specifically mean that you have enabled **Action** -> **Go to report** on the textbox (i.e. a drillthrough report)? This is not the same as a subreport. If so, where are you seeing this, specifically? I cannot replicate this in Visual Studio - with a similar expression I get no option to drillthrough where the expression is evaluating to `Nothing`. Can you please add more detail of your scenario, i.e. screenshots and data to show the issue and how someone could replicate it?

Comment: Hey @IanPreston, can you change your comment to answer. I had made a mistake. I was using wrong field name in the expression.

Comment: Thanks, @NadeemYousuf, I have added as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you specifically mean that you have enabled **Action** -> **Go to report** on the textbox (i.e. a drillthrough report)? This is not the same as a subreport.

As you've described it, it should be working as you expect. I cannot replicate your issue in Visual Studio - with a similar expression I get no option to drillthrough where the expression is evaluating to `Nothing`.

I would start by recreating the textbox/action and see if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work. Faced the same Issue

```
=IIF(Fields!DeptName.Value="Department Total", 0 , "TimekeeperTitlesMainBECReport")
```